# Virtual environment creates with pip version 9, pip --version shows version 20

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

**PROBLEM**

I want to create a virtual environment (`$ python3 -m venv venv`) and see `pip list` give me version 20 every single time.

**Symptoms**

When I create a virtual environment, I get an outdated version of pip ...

```
╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ python3 -m venv venv

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ source venv/bin/activate

(venv) ╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
setuptools (39.0.1)
```

So, I investigate local packages

```
(venv) ╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ python3
>>> import os
>>> ... import site
>>> ... print(site.getsitepackages())
>>> ... os.listdir(site.getsitepackages()[0])
['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

And I look in my local file system to view contents of pip

```
(venv) ╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ deactivate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           127 ↵

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ python3 -m pip install -U pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.0.2)

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ ll /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages | grep 'pip'

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ ll /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages | grep 'pip'                                                                                                                                                                                                       1 ↵
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages': No such file or directory

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ ll  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages | grep 'pip'                                                                                                                                                                                                        1 ↵
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Mar  5 14:07 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar  5 14:07 pip-9.0.1.egg-info
```

Now I check the version of pip

```
╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ ll /home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip
total 20K
-rw-r--r--  1 mat mat  455 Mar 14 11:30 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 13 mat mat 4.0K Mar 14 11:30 _internal
-rw-r--r--  1 mat mat  632 Mar 14 11:30 __main__.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 mat mat 4.0K Mar 14 11:30 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x 19 mat mat 4.0K Mar 14 11:30 _vendor
```

So, you can see that `python3 -m venv venv` looks to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` but `pip3 --version` looks to `/home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip`

**Question #1**

How might I configure *python3* such that when I enter `python3 -m venv venv` then activate the virtual environment that I can enter `pip list` and see version 20, just like I get outside the virtual environment?

**Question #2**

I assume that because I enter `pip --version` and it shows version 20 that when I create a virtual environment it too should have version 20.  Why is this not so?

**Question #3**

The output of the following shows pip version 9:

```
╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ ll  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages | grep 'pip'                                                                                                                                                                                                        1 ↵
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4.0K Mar  5 14:07 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar  5 14:07 pip-9.0.1.egg-info
```

So, why doesn't this command below change `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to have version 20?

```
╭─mat@superelectron ~/code/mist-alpha ‹cassandra-api*› 
╰─$ python3 -m pip install -U pip
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/mat/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (20.0.2)
```